# Termux Vs The Terminal on Ubuntu. Getting different output from the same command

Tags: ubuntu, bash

So the command `info -a bash` in Termux gives me a cool break down of bash. Its a very long detailed explanation broken up in to topics like Command Line Editing, History, Expansion and many others.

My problem is that when I use the same command on ubuntu it gives me the simple man page I would get by running "man bash". I want to go threw the termux file on my laptop, I know that i can just adb pull the file but I would like to understand whats going on.

Also it's not the format of the output the changes its the content of the output it's self.

Apologies for the poor explanation.

Comment: ubuntu runs *dash* not *bash* as default. type `bash` to change the shell temporary

Comment: Well thats interesting., So Mr@alecx what I am to do is run the "bash" 1st and then my command. Thank you for that its very helpful. It didn't give me the output I was looking for but it did teach me something new.